# SFSpeechRecognizer AVAudioNode.mm:565: CreateRecordingTap: required condition is false: _recordingTap == nil

Tags: swift3, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, ios8.3, xcode8

> ERROR:    [0x1a9c3cb40] >avae> AVAudioNode.mm:565: CreateRecordingTap: required condition is false: _recordingTap == nil
>       2017-09-05 10:53:48.547091+0530 Siri[4223:1598099] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: _recordingTap == nil'
>       *** First throw call stack:
>       (0x183966fe0 0x1823c8538 0x183966eb4 0x19db28180 0x19db9c530 0x19db9a130 0x1000ca698 0x1000cc8bc 0x1000c94a4 0x100adda50 0x100adda10 0x100ae2b78 0x1839150c8 0x183912ce4 0x183842da4 0x1852ad074 0x189afdc9c 0x1000d587c 0x18285159c)
>       libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

**Is there any Way to resolve this.**

Reading all the other possible solutions and apple developer documents. I have made sure to removetap and then install tap still i am facing this error.

What i am doing is i have implemented some commands in this. Once user speaks any command the application performs the action. Everything is going great but sometimes the application crashes and gives the error.

Is there any other idea about what the issue could be?

Any help will really be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Check audioEngine.inputNode need remove when stop record. Try this code to stop audioEngine. It's the same question with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42238195/avspeechrecognizer-required-condition-is-false-recordingtap-nil-error-in-s)

```
audioEngine.stop()
recognitionRequest?.endAudio()
audioEngine.inputNode?.removeTap(onBus: 0)
```